# Путаются элементы после Shared Preferences

Tags: android

Доброго вечера.

```
String[] tasks = new String[]{<элементы>};  
Set<String> sTasks = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(tasks))
```

Кладем в SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings=context.getSharedPreferences("settings", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        if(isClearing){
            editor.clear();
        }else {
            editor.putStringSet("Имя1", sTasks);
        }
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Достаем:

```
Set<String> tasks2 = (HashSet<String>)this.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAll().get("Имя1");
```

Элементы перепутаны. Где я ступил? :(

UPD:
Выдает ошибку на попытке достать из настроек в LinkedHashSet:

```
LinkedHashSet<String> task = (LinkedHashSet<String>)this.getSharedPreferences(MainActivit‌​y.STORAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAll().get(name);
```

Говорит, что "ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashSet".

Не понимаю, где он хеш нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) не гарантирует сохранение порядка элементов. Чтобы удалить повторяющиеся элементы с сохранением их порядка, вам нужно использовать [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

[Пример](https://ideone.com/n2WpkG):

```
String[] tasks = new String[]{"e", "a", "c", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a"};  
Set<String> sTasks = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(tasks));
System.out.println(sTasks);  // [a, b, c, d, e]
Set<String> sTasks1 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(tasks));
System.out.println(sTasks1);  // [e, a, c, b, d]
```

С сохранением порядка элементов в `SharedPreferences` [сложнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18780264/7485582). Сохранить можно Set, и `SharedPreferences` не знает о том, нужно ли сохранять порядок элементов, поэтому, вообще говоря, так сохранять строки не получится. Решить эту проблему можно такими способами:

- пройти в цикле по получившемуся `LinkedHashSet`, сохраняя значения в строки формата `"value_" + i` и таким же образом получая обратно.
- преобразовать множество в JSON-строку и сохранить её. Потом получать эту строку и преобразовывать обратно в коллекцию.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: В общем, нашел я такую тему. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779331/android-hashset-cannot-be-cast-to-linkedhashset. И кажется SharedPreferences просто не гарантируют порядка элементов. Не понимаю зачем так сделали...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашел я такую тему.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779331/android-hashset-cannot-be-cast-to-linkedhashset
SharedPreferences работают с HashSet, поэтому для сохранения порядка надо использовать ArrayList или Json.

Comment: К сожалению, сохранить ArrayList в SharedPreferences напрямую нельзя. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html